# Access class within another folder in the same project (Xcode)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am currently editing my project structure to contains folders with source files. Within the SmartCarOAuthSDK class, I am trying to access the classes from the various folders. But currently, I am not sure how to import the files containing in the other folders

[Current project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Efito.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import SmartCartOAuthSDK/SmartCartOAuthSDK.swift
```

Comment: What I mean is I want to important SmartCarOAuthRequest.swift from the AuthRequest folder into the class SmartCarOAuthSDK.swift. I've tried import AuthRequest/SmartCarOAuthRequest.swift but that didnt work